# R Replacing a Substring with a new Value

Tags: r, regex

I cannot get R to replace a substring with a new value.

I have a data frame (orderData) with several rows under the column "`ITM_DESC`" that have the value of "some text Force 10, some other text"

I want to find " Force 10" and replace it with " Force10"...removing the space between the e and 1.

I've tried various permutations of the code below. It does not throw an error but, it also does not modify the dataframe.

```
orderData$ITM_DESC <- replace(
  orderData$ITM_DESC, orderData$ITM_DESC == " Force 10", "Force10"
)
```

Comment: You’ve tagged your question with [tag:dplyr] but your code isn’t using dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide a reproductible example so we can not know your problem. Yet, you can try:

```
   orderData$ITM_DESC <- gsub(" Force 10", "Force10",orderData$ITM_DESC)
```

A common problem is that maybe your space is not a space. It works with some but not all? May be more than one space or a tab type that looks even to sight, but are different in programming languages.

```
   orderData$ITM_DESC <- gsub(" Force\\s+10", "Force10",orderData$ITM_DESC)
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work. I load up the data frame, run this code and then do a View(orderData) on the console. When i filter the ITM_DESC column, i can still find Force 10 with a space rather than no space. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: That got it. Thanks! I appreciate your help.